# Windows is not able to connect to router through WiFi after password change

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I'm using a TP-LINK router. Just now I changed the router password and then I'm trying to connect to my router through WiFi.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Windows was not able to connect TP-LINK_F01C49
```

Comment: Changed the Admin password for the router or the passphrase for WiFi security?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have changed your password. Disconnect your Windows from router (click on `Forget this network` option) and then connect your Windows again to your router with your new password. You will be connected!